# vba if cell contains value which matches file name then say ok else say not ok?

Tags: excel, vba

I have updated my code to explain a bit more about what it is im trying to do...

i am generating a random string with numbers and letters and creating a text file with the name of the random generated string, in this case im calling my string: `strPassword`

Now once the text file is created i want to perform a check to see if this file name exists. 
So this means retrieving the random string which was created and saved as the file name.

If the file exists i should get a message saying ok otherwise it should say not ok.

I am trying to retrieve the file name by calling `strPassword`

For some reason its telling me the file does not exist so I can only assume its having trouble getting the value of `strPassword`. it appears once a random number has been generated it forgets what was generated, so is there a way I can save strPassword  to a variable or session or some kind of memory to perform a check for the filename later?

When my cell A1 is clicked it performs a check to see if the filename exists in cell S32, if it doesn't exists a message is show and the file is created with the random string `strPassword` and saved.

Then If I want to type this string name into cell S32 it should say file exists because it has just created it, but its not its saying file does not exist.

For instance if I have a text file that's filename was randomly generated by usiung strPassword located at:

```
P:\XBQILGHD.txt
```

So in my cell in excel if I was to type:

```
XBQILGHD (which is the strPassword value)
```

then I would get a message that says 'OK' otherwise I would get a message that says 'NOT OK'

can someone please show me what I am doing wrong here?
thanks

```
    Dim strPassword As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
strPassword = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd + 65)) & strPassword
Else
strPassword = Int((9 * Rnd) + 1) & strPassword
End If
Next i


If Dir("P:\" & strPassword & ".txt") <> "" Then
MsgBox "File exists"
Else
MSG3 = MsgBox("Hi " & Range("N9").Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Unfortunately you have used up your entire allowance for this month." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "You will not be able to continue with this request. Please wait until next month, when your request allowance will be reset." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Think this is an Error?" & vbNewLine & "Contac us at NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk to make an appeal.", vbOKOnly, "Important Notice!")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("P:\" & strPassword & ".txt", True)
a.WriteLine (strPassword)
a.Close
End If
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with these password strings? And what error do you get executing this?

Comment: You don't even reference any Excel objects...

Comment: It seems that you are trying to generate file name. Your purpose is to check file existence or creation? Edit your question with consistent and relevant info.

Comment: i am generating a random file name using random password. I then want to query this string to check if the filename exists?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? What error do you get? I understood you had problems with the last part (checking for an existing file), but your solution should work. Maybe you just need to get rid of the " * " in "*.txt", because that seems to be misplaced

Comment: @EngJon I have updated my question, please let me know if you understand what I am trying to do now abit better, thanks

Comment: So, you're generating a random file name and then you want to check if there's any file with that name on P:, if it is -> "File exists" and nothing, if not -> give a strange messagebox and create the file. Correct?

Comment: OK. where in the code is the part of checking cell S32? i only see a static check for "P:\I1C3R3T8H4.txt". If you are generating the filename beforehand, I don't see why you need to have that value in a specific cell (S32) at all. Wouldn't it be sufficient to just check for "If Dir("P:\" & strPassword & ".txt") <> "" Then..."?

Comment: @EngJon sorry I have amended my code as I was testing something but it should say If Dir("P:\" & strPassword & ".txt") <> "" Then - I have changed this back now

Comment: Try debugging the variables. You can either output the full path with a MsgBox or into an excel cell. So you can check whether this path is valid manually.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem try it: in file ttp.txt was saved your pwd

```
    Dim strPassword As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
    strPassword = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd + 65)) & strPassword
    Else
    strPassword = Int((9 * Rnd) + 1) & strPassword
    End If
    Next i


       If Dir("P:\ttp.txt") <> "" Then
       MsgBox "File exists"
       Else
       MSG3 = MsgBox("Hi " & Range("N9").Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Unfortunately you have used   up your   `enter code here`entire allowance for this month." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "You will not be able to continue with this request. Please wait until next month, when your request allowance will be reset." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Think this is an Error?" & vbNewLine & "Contac us at NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk to make an appeal.", vbOKOnly, "Important Notice!")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("P:\ttp.txt", True)
a.WriteLine (strPassword)
a.Close

End If
```

Comment: no I don't think this is right, I am generating a random combination of letters and numbers using strPassword and saving this as the text filename so say HGWQYQA was generated then the text fille will be called HGWQYQA so when we search for the file to see if it exists we used strPassword  which should be HGWQYQA.txt and we should get a file exists message

Comment: Ok but in your code the strPassowrd change always so the file not exists always